# What is the difference between 'x = y = 0', 'x = 0; y = 0;', and 'int x = 0; int y = 0;' with respect to execution?

Tags: c++, assembly, clang

I'm just wondering if there is any difference between the following statements as far as how they are compiled and executed on the Clang compiler without any optimizations:

#### 1

```
int x;
int y;
y = x = 5;
```

#### 2

```
int x = 5;
int y = 5;
```

#### 3

```
int x;
int y;
x = 5;
y = 5;
```

Comment: Since they all have the same effect, it's entirely up to how the compiler decides to implement that effect.

Comment: Maybe the optimizer will see that you aren't ever using x and y and just take them out or maybe replace with immediate values whenever you reference x and y. For this question you have to say what compiler you're using and what optimization settings, and you should check the assembler output yourself first

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I edited my question to be a little more specific.

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: Why make a question and add an answer to it just to fish some more reputation?

Comment: Its a feature of the site to allow you to add an answer when creating your question.  I did the work myself and wanted to share it on here in case anyone else is curious.

Comment: Nothing wrong with providing own answer but honestly i don't know the purpose of the orig question. Are you planning to write initializations in a different way from now on because you discover "the one true way" gives a smaller number of assembly instructions on your particular compiler on default optimization settings??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I compiled each of the above statements with Clang using the following command:

```
clang++ -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel test.cpp
```

Their assembly came out identical:

```
    .section __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .globl   _main
    .align   4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    push rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_offset rbp, -16
    mov rbp, rsp
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register rbp
    mov eax, 0
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 8], 0
    mov dword ptr [rbp - 12], 0
    pop rbp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.subsections_via_symbols
```

This doesn't mean it's true for all compilers/languages, nor does it illustrate how Clang is handling each of the three statements.  I.e., does it compile any particular code snippet more quickly?

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difference as any decent compiler will combine the declarations with the initialisations.  Having said that, it's entirely up to the compiler what it implements for each case.

Answer (score 0):

As far as optimization is concerned there's no difference in these statement for built in types.But for user defined types it matters.
Let's say I have class "Compiler".

```
Compiler c = c1; // 1)
Compiler c;      // 2)
   c = c2.
```

In 1 there will be 1 call to copy constructor of a class whereas in 2nd case there will be two calls first to default constructor and second to assignment operator.
This also happens for built in types but there size is too small to make any difference in optimization.